# How can I use JQ to pick out a parent whose child is hr.strong?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I have a bunch of containers with class .block. Some of those containers have an element hr.strong in them, some don't. Sample:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <hr class="strong">
        </div>
        <!-- end row --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- end container-fluid -->



<div class="container-fluid block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            NO HR HERE
        </div>
        <!-- end row --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- end container-fluid -->
```

I want to apply CSS (`padding:0`) only to .block that has hr.strong in it. How can I use JQ to pick out a parent whose child is hr.strong?

If there is a way to do with CSS only - that would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selector.closest('.block'); This tells it to search up the dom for nearest element with given selector.

```
$("hr.strong").closest('.block').css("background","red");
```

```js
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $("hr.strong").closest('.block').css("background","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <hr class="strong">
        </div>
        <!-- end row --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- end container-fluid -->



<div class="container-fluid block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            NO HR HERE
        </div>
        <!-- end row --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end container --> 
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use that, because parent of hr is .row, but I need to select .block instead.

Comment: Wait - that worked:
$("hr.strong").parent().parent().parent().parent().css("padding","0");

Comment: Use $("hr.strong").closest('.block').css("background","red");

Comment: One more Qn - If I want this applied only to home page (it has body.home), where do I add that .home?

Comment: If it's wrapped in a div with class of home then you can just change your selector to $('.home hr.strong').closest......

Comment: You can use any selector you need to: $("body.home hr.strong").closest('.block').css("background","red");

Comment: Or .home would work for anything with a class of home: $(".home hr.strong").closest('.block').css("background","red");

Answer (score 0):

loop through every hr with strong class, then get the parent with the class block

```
$('hr.strong').each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('div.block');
    $(parent).css("padding","0px");
})
```

Comment: That is probably more error proof rather than `$("hr.strong").parent().parent().parent().parent().css("padding","0");`